# Please help me why am I getting a negative value when using russian peasant algorithm when there is a negative input

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I've tried using Russian peasant using recursion. Below is the code

```
public static int russianPeasantForMultiply(int a, int b){
    if(b == 1) return a;
    if(a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
    int res = 0;
    if((b & 1) != 0){
        res += a;
    }

    return res + russianPeasantForMultiply(a << 1, b >> 1);
}
```

It is working correctly for all inputs. However, I am unable to understand why is it working with negative inputs. Let's say a = 8, b = -4. The value of "a" overflows and then becomes a negative value. And later somehow I have the output -32 on the screen. Tried debugging the code using print statements, and here's the output for each stack call of the recursion.

```
> 
C:\Users\s\Documents\A_Work_space>java RussianPeasant
8
-4
a = 32
b = -1
res = 32 ,
a = 64
b = -1
res = 64 ,
a = 128
b = -1
res = 128 ,
a = 256
b = -1
res = 256 ,
a = 512
b = -1
res = 512 ,
a = 1024
b = -1
res = 1024 ,
a = 2048
b = -1
res = 2048 ,
a = 4096
b = -1
res = 4096 ,
a = 8192
b = -1
res = 8192 ,
a = 16384
b = -1
res = 16384 ,
a = 32768
b = -1
res = 32768 ,
a = 65536
b = -1
res = 65536 ,
a = 131072
b = -1
res = 131072 ,
a = 262144
b = -1
res = 262144 ,
a = 524288
b = -1
res = 524288 ,
a = 1048576
b = -1
res = 1048576 ,
a = 2097152
b = -1
res = 2097152 ,
a = 4194304
b = -1
res = 4194304 ,
a = 8388608
b = -1
res = 8388608 ,
a = 16777216
b = -1
res = 16777216 ,
a = 33554432
b = -1
res = 33554432 ,
a = 67108864
b = -1
res = 67108864 ,
a = 134217728
b = -1
res = 134217728 ,
a = 268435456
b = -1
res = 268435456 ,
a = 536870912
b = -1
res = 536870912 ,
a = 1073741824
b = -1
res = 1073741824 ,
a = -2147483648
b = -1
res = -2147483648 ,
-32
```

Please help me understand why is this happening.

Comment: You're doing bit shifting and producing quite high values. It's entirely possible that you get a `1` to overflow to the sign position.

Comment: @VLAZ So, the integer "a" overflowed and then had it's sign changed? is that how overflow works?

Comment: Yes, each number is represented by `1`s and `0`. One position is reserved for the sign so, perhaps you can have `01001` where the first bit is the sign, the other 4 define a number, thus you can define positive numbers with the first bit `0`, e.g., 9 is `00101` and a negative number has a first bit of `1`, so `-9` is `10101`. When you bit-shift left, a `9` twice, you first get `01010` (decimal 10) and then `10100` (decimal -4). So, you're likely pushing a bit too far left, for an `int` type.

Comment: Thank you for the info @VLAZ, I have understood that at some point the number becomes negative because we are occupying the bit which represents the sign of the integer. However, I still don't get why would a number like 32 change to -32. if we keep doing left shift should it not become 0 after becomes negative instead of -32. and the first negative number would be a very large negative number right?. Like the one in the screenshot I've put in my question.

Comment: Note: no screenshot of text information. Your console output is pure text, so you could and should post it as nicely formatted text!

Comment: Study [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and you'll understand what's going on with your code. Also, try outputting the values in binary as well as decimal: `System.out.println(a + "\t" + Integer.toBinaryString(a));`

Comment: Having looked at it more closely, this is an interesting issue where you are getting the correct result due to how many times this is being called recursively.

Answer (score 0):

the shifting produces quite high values.

For potential values

1. higher than `2,147,483,647` or
2. below `-2,147,483,648`,

which are the biggest numbers that can be represented by an `int`, better use `long`s:

```
public static long russianPeasantForMultiply(long a, long b){
    if(b == 1) return a;
    if(a == 0 || b == 0) return 0;
    int res = 0;
    if((b & 1) != 0){
        res += a;
    }

    return res + russianPeasantForMultiply(a << 1, b >> 1);
}
```

Note: a `long` ranges

1. from `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808`
2. to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

Comment: Tahnk you for the answer. The problem is not that I am unable to multiply large numbers. The problem is that I am unable to understand why is it working on negative numbers.

Comment: This suggested answer won't solve the issue. It will still overflow to the negative numbers, but will just take twice as many bit shifts to do so.

Comment: take a look at @VLAZ's response